# In Groovy SwingBuilder, how do i attach Keystrokes for menu Item?

Tags: groovy

Recently i read about Groovy Swing Builder, and i want to add keystrokes listeners for menuItems. I have the following code:

```
import javax.swing.*
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
swing = new SwingBuilder()
menuHelper = swing.action(name: "Hello",mnemonic:'P',acclerator: 'ctrl P',keyStrokes:'ctrl P', closure : { println "Hi you have used Menu via keyStroke" })
frame = swing.frame(title : "Anto", show : true , pack : true, size :[100,100] ){
        panel{
        menuBar {
        menu('File'){
                menuItem(action : menuHelper)
                }
        }
}
}
```

I have created `menuHelper` `action` for this purpose and targeted to `menuItem` and its not working via KeyStrokes. However its working when i click on my menu `File` and and then  `Hello`, thus printing :

```
   //Output: Hi you have used Menu via keyStroke
```

I don't know where i went wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
acclerator
```

should be

```
accelerator
```

Comment: No, `SwingBuilder` delegates calls to a Factory object (in this case `groovy.swing.factory.ActionFactory`).  This class picks the parameters it requires out of the map you passed in.  If you have a typo in a parameter name, and it is not required, then it will just assume you didn't specify it

Comment: Oh thats fine..., but how does you have a knowledge like this? What book you read for Groovy ?

Comment: Best book IMO for Groovy is Groovy in Action ([2nd Edition out soon](http://www.manning.com/koenig2/)).  Found the answer to the last comment by looking at the source code for Groovy though.  You can [download it with subversion](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Building+Groovy+from+Source) and then have at look how bits of it work :-)

Comment: I'm learning Groovy from Groovy in action too , but first edition... Anyways thanks for answer and suggestion :D